# How to connect mysql with Java using hibernate? Exception:No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.tutorial_jpa

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, maven

At the beginning I wanted to write a simple program to connect in Java to MySQL using hibernate. Program don't find a persistence provider for EntityManager. Unfortunately, there are still some exceptions. At this point, they are like this:

Exceptions at this moment:

```html
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=53702:D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.1.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.5\byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.4.1.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.47\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\17-ea+11\javafx-controls-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\17-ea+11\javafx-graphics-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\17-ea+11\javafx-base-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\17-ea+11\javafx-fxml-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\17-ea+11\javafx-web-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\17-ea+11\javafx-media-17-ea+11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar -p C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\17-ea+11\javafx-media-17-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.2.0\ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\17-ea+11\javafx-web-17-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\17-ea+11\javafx-fxml-17-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.2.0\ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\tilesfx\11.48\tilesfx-11.48.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\17-ea+11\javafx-base-17-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\17-ea+11\javafx-controls-17-ea+11-win.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\synedra\validatorfx\0.1.13\validatorfx-0.1.13.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\Uczelnia\Java\demo1232\target\classes;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.0\controlsfx-11.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\formsfx\formsfx-core\11.3.2\formsfx-core-11.3.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\bootstrapfx\bootstrapfx-core\0.4.0\bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\17-ea+11\javafx-graphics-17-ea+11-win.jar -m lab2.dziennik/lab2.dziennik.Main
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:467)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:366)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.hibernate.tutorial_jpa
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at lab2.dziennik/lab2.dziennik.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application lab2.dziennik.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

- peristence.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Kacper"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

- main:

```html
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory e = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa");
        testBaza1 t = new testBaza1();
        t.setId(2);
        t.setNazwa("bob");

        testBaza t1 = new testBaza();
        t1.setNazwa("xxx");


        EntityManager e1 = e.createEntityManager();
        e1.persist(t);
        e1.persist(t1);
        e1.getTransaction().commit();
        
        e.close();
    }
```

- testBaza:

```html
package lab2.dziennik;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="TEST")
public class testBaza {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id1){
        id=id1;
    }

    @Column(name="nazwa")
    private String nazwa;

    public String getNazwa()
    {
        return nazwa;
    }

    public void setNazwa(String n){
        nazwa=n;
    }


}
```

- testBaza1

```html
package lab2.dziennik;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TEST1")
public class testBaza1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id1){
        id=id1;
    }

    @Column(name="nazwa")
    private String nazwa;

    public String getNazwa()
    {
        return nazwa;
    }

    public void setNazwa(String n){
        nazwa=n;
    }
}
```

- maven dependency:

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay, I wanted the post to be transparent. I'll take it into account next time.

Comment: Instead of image add it as text.

Comment: Okay, but I have exception: INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath and like before.

Comment: Add your exceptions and any other information to your question, not as comments or images.

Comment: I changed this.

Comment: When I did it throws even more exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

"dirver" class? - I did not go through the complete Stack Trace since it is quite difficult to read :) Could you maybe write it as a code? :)

Try changing "dirver" -> "driver"

[image: dirver_class]

Also some drivers need setters and they need to be written correctly:

[image: setNazwa]

Comment: Oh, okay, I corrected, but continues to throw exceptions.

Comment: I have updated the exceptions in my post :)

Comment: You could try making the fields public. I do not know why do I have negative ratings - If anyone could explain that.. I am also new here :)